# How to get Year, Month, Day from a specific date-string in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I am unable to get a regex match for a JavaScript date in Erlang via:

```
re:run("2018-05-25", <<"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$">>).
```

Although, this test succeeds as a regular regex, see here: https://regex101.com/r/bEfNgG/1

Furthermore, I have attempted to pattern-match the date via but to no avail(45 is the charcode for "-").

```
[Y, $45, M, $45, D] = "2018-05-25".
```

Would you please glance over this and give me a tip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Y, M, D] = string:split("2018-05-25", "-", all).
```

Answer (score 1):

As noted at the beginning of the `re` [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html), single backslash is interpreted by the literal string syntax, so you need to backslash it to preserve it in the regex:

```
 re:run("2018-05-25", "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}$").
```

Answer (score 0):

After some searching in other projects I found this:

```
<<Year:4/binary, _:1/binary, Month:2/binary, _:1/binary, Day/binary>> = <<"2018-05-25">>.
```

This helped me get the job done.